# Raspberry Pi 3 Connecting to Bluetooth audio device on Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, audio, pi-3, bluetooth, raspbian-jessie

I am trying to connect to a Bluetooth audio device on fully updated Raspberry Pi 3 running Jessie using the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
Changing discoverable on succeeded
[CHG] Controller YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY Discoverable: yes
[bluetooth]# pairable on
Changing pairable on succeeded
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent 
Default agent request successful
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
...
[NEW] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Device Name
...
[bluetooth]# pair XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Attempting to pair with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[CHG] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Connected: yes
[CHG] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX UUIDs:
    ########-####-####-####-############
    ########-####-####-####-############
    ########-####-####-####-############
[CHG] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[bluetooth]# trust XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[CHG] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Trusted: yes
Changing XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Attempting to connect to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

One the GUI Desktop a popup appears:

```
Connection failed -
GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.Failed: No such file or directory. Try to connect manually.
```

Both Bluetooth devices I've tried work with other devices

I've run both

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
hcitool scan
```

and was able to see the device under scan

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of audio device are you trying to connect to?  Is it a set of Bluetooth speakers for playing Pi audio?  Perhaps Bluetooth headphones, again for playing audio?  Is it a Bluetooth audio source such as a cell phone or car and you want to play audio from speakers attached to your Pi?

Comment: Maybe updating rpi firmware might solve it and then sudo service bluetooth restart && sudo service bluez restart

Comment: @Kolban I've tried both Bose SoundLink and Bluetooth to 30 pin adapter (my ultimate goal)

Answer (score 2):

Try to do:

```
pulseaudio --start
```

And after:

```
[bluetooth]# connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be nice if you listed some information as to why this answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty old, But even now I had come across similar issue:
I will detail you how I was able to fix this for current version of raspbian 10.

(i) Install Pulse audio tool

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

(ii) Start Pulse audio

```
pulseaudio --start
```

(iii) Now turn on your bluetooth speaker , and make it discoverable, then type this in rpi
terminal

```
bluetoothctl
```

(iv) Power On the bluetooth

```
power on
```

(v) Set bluetooth to default agent

```
agent on
default-agent
```

(vi) start the scan

```
scan on
```

Now you will see the list of devices copy the mac address of your speaker

```
pair xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

trust the device so that next time speaker turns off and on it automatically connects
trust xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
and finally connect

```
connect xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
sudo reboot now
```

After reboot your device should automatically connect, and any audio should be transmitted,

If not you may have to externally try making bluetooth speaker your default speaker
Try this: Go to config.txt and disable snd_bcm2835 default output, type in following command

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

scroll-down till you find `dtparam=audio=on` and replace it with `#dtparam=audio=on`
save the file using `ctrl+O` and enter, then `ctrl+X`. Reboot your pi, sound should be coming out to speaker.

Hope this helps!
source: https://rpios.blogspot.com/2020/09/connect-bluetooth-speaker-to-raspberry.html

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem .I find that it works if you install blueman and run that. Then run `pulseaudio --start`. Open up blueman on the devices tab  and search for devices. It should then find your device. Click pair and make sure it is set as a trusted device. Then go onto **pavucontrol** and set the output device to **high fidelity A2DP**  or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
 pulse audio --start
 bluetoothctl
 pair XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
 connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Comment: Could you please give some kind of explanation as to what this code does. This does not answer the question.